# We couldn't connect to the catalog server for this add-n

Tags: ms-office, office-js, excel-addins, office-app

I just realized that many add-ins cannot be loaded in Excel Online (Chrome):

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue reported through StackOverflow and other channels. We're investigating this as a high priority issue. We'll let you know when the issue is resolved.

Comment: @Sudhi Ramamurthy Seems this error is not solved again. We build a powerpoint content add-in and we get this error when opening presentation mode in powerpoint online.

Comment: @SoftTimur We are having the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: We have the same problem in Word online. Works fine on Word Desktop and in Word Online if deploying the add-in from the office admin tool. Only if using the add in Word Online installed from the store it fails